# Windows 7 admin denied access to taskmgr, system32 dir

Tags: windows-7, security, administrator

I have a Windows 7 (32-bit) box with 2 users, both admins (my wife and I are both developers).  My admin account was created during Windows setup, hers was created later.  Both accounts are in the same groups, yet we have VERY different permissions.  In the beta and RC, both accounts worked identically (RC to RTM was a fresh install on this box, not an upgrade).

I have a C:\bin folder with the sysinternals utilities and a bunch of other stuff.  Running anything in there or in system32 just works on my account, on hers I get access denied errors (cannot access file or path).  If I right click and try Run As Administrator, I still get the same thing!!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on the folder permissions and double check that she has control.

It is possible that as the folder was created under your user, only your user has permission over it instead of the administrators group.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a third admin account and seeing if the problem persists there? I mean I know it doesn't tell you what the source of the problem is, but if you're a pragmatic person just interested in getting it working, creating another account and moving to it might be the fastest way to get things done.

Also, I wish I had a developer wife :P